# submit for password form no longer working

Tags: javascript

```js
class Mess {
 MessyMethod() {
   startSession = function () {
     document.querySelector('.rds-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('form submitted');
     });
   }
 }
}
```

```html
<form class="rds-form">
  <input /><button id="continueButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Guys I have a project whose JavaScript logic has something like this:

```
export class Mess {
  constructor(title, username) {
    this.title = title;
    this.username = username;
    this.container = document.getElementById('originalContainer');
  }

  MessyMethod() {

    this.startSession = function () {
       var self = this;
       let pwForm = pwAuthForm();
       let div = document.createElement('div');
       document.templates = [];
       div.innerHTML = pwForm;
       this.container.appendChild(div);

       document.querySelector('.rds-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
         alert('form submitted!');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

the index.html is:

```
<form class="rds-form">
  <input /><button id="continueButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So the above does not work in terms of successfully submitting unless I pull that `document.querySelector()` out of the `this.startSession` which inside of `MessyMethod`. I have been asked where is `startSession` being called, well, it has not been called anywhere. It was working before when `document.querySelector("continueButton").addEventListener("click", function ())`

but my understanding is that this is bad form, it should target the class of the form and listen for submit, otherwise a user could click anywhere in the page and the form will submit. Am I going down a wrong path here?

Comment: You don't seams to ever call that `MessyMethod` function. Or if you do, it's not in the code you've provied.

Comment: Why can't `document.querySelector('.rds-form')` be part of the constructor call and then add the listener in messy method?

Comment: @Nicolas, sorry, I added where I called MessyMethod functions.

Comment: Where is this.startSession() called?

Comment: @user2258152, I just added where `startSession` is being called. thanks for asking.

Comment: I don't think you are ever calling startSession

Comment: You should consider creating a [mcve]. You never call any of those functions. You could have an infinite stack of function being called in function, if you never start by calling one somewhere, like in a script tag, none of those function would be called.

Comment: @Nicolas, I put together a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working

Your issue is how you call the `startSession`

here is working example (same code):

```js
    class Mess {
        constructor(title, username) {
          this.title = title;
          this.username = username;
          this.container = document.getElementById('originalContainer');
        }
      
        MessyMethod() {



          this.startSession = function () {
             var self = this;
             document.querySelector('.rds-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               alert('form submitted!');
            });
             
             //let pwForm = pwAuthForm();
             //let div = document.createElement('div');
             //document.templates = [];
             //div.innerHTML = pwForm;
             //this.container.appendChild(div);

  
          }
        }
      }

    // I added these 3 lines
    var mess = new Mess("title !","user name !")  
    mess.MessyMethod()
    mess.startSession()
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <form class="rds-form">
        <input /><button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

if you want to keep the same code skelaton (i suggest to refactor)

be aware that `startSession` method is only built when you run `MessyMethod`

so you need to call `MessyMethod` first then call `startSession` to actually add the submit event listener

Comment: the `startSession` function is not called inside the class of `Mess`its called inside the class of `FormSession`

Comment: @Daniel you have defined two `startSession` methods in two different classes. `FormSession` and `MessyMethod` . 
what `startSession` you want to call ? it's not the same method. when you do `this.startSession` insode `MessyMethod` you are actually building new method fro the class.

Comment: I want to call the `startSession` in `MessyMethod`.

Comment: I need both `startSessions` they are each in separate classes that represent different types of sessions, technically they are subclasses but I wanted to keep things simple here.

Comment: **first you said** _the `startSession` function is not called inside the class of `Mess`its called inside the class of `FormSession`_  **then you said :** _I want to call the startSession in MessyMethod_  **Please decide what you want**
from your question i understood that you want to _I want to call the startSession in MessyMethod_ and i provided you an example of how it can be done

Comment: is not that simple, I am working with code snippets that were just thrown at me with no explanation. For example, this thing was working before without having to call `startSession` anywhere. It was working when it was `document.querySelector('#continueButton').addEventListener('click', function(){})` but my understanding of JavaScript, that is not the best way to handle the submit button. so I corrected it to what you see now, and wondering why it will not work. You say its because `startSession` has to be called, it was not called before though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onSubmit listener directly on the form instead

```
function submit () {
  alert('form submitted!')
}

<form class="rds-form" onsubmit="submit()">
  <input /><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: OP is not using React

Comment: That's fair but you can still do that without react.

Comment: Not with the syntax you have provided, that is JSX. Vanilla JS is `onsubmit="myFunction()"`